# Wont delete via ajax live call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When i press the delete button, it won't delete the content.
I think there is something wrong on the ajax delete call

ajax-file.php

```
    $('.delete_update').live("click",function() {

        var ID = $(this).attr("id");
        var dataString = 'msg_id='+ ID;

        if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this update? There is NO undo!")) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "delete_data.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
            $("div#bar"+ID).slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
        }
    });

    }

return false;
});

<div class="accordionButton" id="bar<?php echo $msg_id; ?>"><?php echo $msg_id; ?>:<?php echo $name; ?>
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $msg_id; ?>" class="delete_update">X</a>
</div>
<div class="accordionContent" style="display: block;"><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
```

delete_data.php

```
<?php
include("db.php");
if($_POST['msg_id'])
{
$id=$_POST['msg_id'];
$id = mysql_escape_String($id);
$sql = "delete from messages where msg_id='$id'";
mysql_query( $sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: So does the click event fired or not? Any error in console? Explain better your issue

Comment: Check with FF/Firebug/Chrome if the Post request is sent, so we know if the js or the php code has the mistake.

Comment: Do you realize anybody could basically delete stuff from your database as you don't validate any input at all ? Also, you shouldn't use `POST` to delete stuff when there's `DELETE` method availabe in HTTP methods.

Comment: It does not do anything at all. The does not run the ajax. So I think it must be something with the button?

Comment: I don't think data are passed correctly `data: { msg_id: dataString }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using latest `jQuery` then use `on` instead of `live` as it's not supported

***Updated for dynamic content**

```
$(document).on("click", '.delete_update', function() {
```

Comment: I use jquery-2.0.3.min.js - I tried to change it - But still not working

Comment: I think it is because the content i trying to delete is loaded through ajax, and that why the delete button does not work?

Comment: Then use `$(document).on("click", '.delete_update', function() {` answer updated

Comment: Now the jquery code runs :) thank - But it does not delete or get the ID.      var ID = $(this).attr("id");
        var dataString = 'msg_id='+ ID;

Comment: It worked now - I didn't connect to the mysql db. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is within this function. 
You're giving $.ajax data object a string.
The function 'normally' only processes javascript objects.

Also be carefull when processing parameters without checking them. 
Have a look at **prepared statements for mysql**.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete_data.php",
        data: dataString, <--- May be wrong because you are using POST
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
        $("div#bar"+ID).slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
    }
```

Try this instead. Try to echo msg_id at the service side script

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete_data.php",
        data: {msg_id:ID},
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
        $("div#bar"+ID).slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
    }
```